# Why would having a reference string "boh@10" cause a crash?

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator

When using the raster calculator in a pyqgis script, I have several layers to process.  When it gets to "boh@10", the processCalculation() call crashes.  I don't see anything in the code that requires that field to be anything other than a QString. Anybody know what's up??

In reference to the question and answers at ...
[Help with scripts for processing raster files with the raster calculator in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92984/help-with-scripts-for-processing-raster-files-with-the-raster-calculator-in-qgis)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been some issue with v2.8. When I upgraded to QGIS 2.10 the problem disappears.